# display a dialog when i click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i ty to display a dialog when i click on a button

in my js part i have

```
   $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $('#create-report').click(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
```

in my html part i have

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <p>hi how are you</p>
</div>

<button id="create-report" >Create new report</button>
```

nothing is displayed and i don't have any error

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` to initially hide the dialog.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;">
    <p>hi how are you</p>
</div>
```

Also make sure that jQuery and jQuery UI are being loaded properly.  This fiddle works:  http://jsfiddle.net/E3Pek/

Comment: don't work, but maybe because my jsp page is an iframe?  if i put the code in another page, that work..

Comment: @roberttrudel Does the markup loaded in the iframe contain jQuery and jQuery UI?  I don't think it would have access to those resources in the parent page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary that you put the style on your div.

Should be like this:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>hi how are you</p>
</div>
```

Remember the order that you have to load the jquery scripts. First load jquery library and then jquery-ui.